# indice indefinido $_FILES

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con $_FILES PHP para subir una foto
Índice indefinido fileToUpload
este es mi codigo

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Seleccionar imagen:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
//el error aparece en $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "El archivo es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "El archivo no es una imagen.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

He intentado de diferentes formas pero el resultado siempre es el mismo:

> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload

Al ejecutar `var_dump($_FILES)` me devuelve:

> array(0) { }

pero si lo ejecuto de esta manera `var_dump($_FILES['foto']['name'])` me sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: **A.** Es muy probable que la ruta de tu archivo esté mal. Por lo que veo, aquí: `$target_dir = "uploads/";`  falta un `/` al principio. Debería ser `$target_dir = "/uploads/";` **B.** Si aún así no funciona depura primero que la ruta esté bien, escribiéndola manualmente, sin variables. Ojo: **sólo para fines de depuración**, luego construyes tus rutas como habitualmente.

Comment: Los códigos html y php que publicas están bien. Los copié y ejecuté y los datos `$_POST` y `$_FILES` pasan correctamente desde el formulario hasta "upload.php". La única manera que veo para que te produzca ese error es que estés accediendo _directamente_ a "upload.php" y no *a través del formulario*. ¿Podrías confirmar cómo estás ejecutando tu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo insertando las líneas de código que tienen que ver con la imagen, dentro del If que valida si el botón name="submit" ha sido presionado. Ademas de validar si la imagen fué cargada en el servidor sin errores, verificando que el código de error distinto de 4.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";

// print_r($_FILES);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] != 4) {

        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 1;

        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "El archivo es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "El archivo no es una imagen.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Saludos

Comment: Ya metí las líneas del código de la imagen dentro del if y funciona bien aún no entiendo porque daba el error pero muchas gracias

Comment: El error se debe a que en la primera ejecución la variable no estaba inicial izada.  Es por eso la validación con la función isset.

Comment: Ok me sirvió de mucho tú ayuda gracias